# addSubview turning my view to default

Tags: ios, swift, addsubview

It seems when i use addSubview to add an image to my viewcontroller, the view is turned to it's view when it loads. Any reason why and how to fix?
Here's my code if needed:

```
 let target = Targets[i]
 bullet = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named:"BulletHole"))
 bullet.frame = CGRectMake(target.center.x,target.center.y,20,20)
 bullet.hidden = false
 self.view.addSubview(bullet)
```

Comment: I just ran your code with a sample image and everything worked fine for me. Could you describe exactly what is going on?

Comment: I have an instance moving in the view, so it has a different position from its starting position. I run this code, and it makes the instance go back to its starting position.

Comment: Then the problem seems to be with your `target` object, which is assigning the position. If it's going back to its starting position, then `center` in  `target` isn't changing.

Comment: sorry i didnt specify, the target isn't the moving instance, i have another image moving and that image changes to its default/starting position everytime i run this code

Comment: No worries :) I tried to answer your question below the best I could. Just let me know if something's not right!

Comment: thanks for the answer, accepted for helping me but still didn't quite answer what I needed, i guess it's hard to explain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image not moving seems to be due to the view inheritance that the line `self.view.addSubview(bullet)` expresses. With this, you are pasting the image onto the whole view itself. If you want it to move with another image you have two options:

1. Move the bullet hole the same way as you move the other image, or
2. add the bullet hole as a subview of the view that is moving, NOT the main view (as in `self.view`)